# UIView inside UIView with Shadow?

Tags: iphone, uiview, shadow

I've been trying to figure out how to draw a shadow for an UIView that was added inside a UIView with addSubview.

I searched online and read the docs, but the Apple docs simply draw new shapes as shown below. I want to use the Core Graphics to add a shadow to the UIView, but am unsure how to do this to a UIView directly.

```
    CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 //CGContextRef myContext = myCGREF;

    CGSize          myShadowOffset = CGSizeMake (10, 10);// 2

    CGContextSetShadow (myContext, myShadowOffset, 0);   // 3

    CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer (myContext, NULL);// 4

    // Your drawing code here// 5

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 0, 1, 0, 1);

    CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (a_view.frame.origin.x, a_view.frame.origin.y , wd, ht));

    CGContextEndTransparencyLayer (myContext);// 6
```

I know I should put this in the SuperView drawRect method, but I don't know how to make it so it adds a shadow to the views I add in addSubView.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late for an answer...

But you could simply pass the graphic context to the child view ; either as a parameter when creating the UIView or via a protocol which you will query within the drawRect function of the child